# Evaluate $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}x\sin \frac 1 x$

Tags: real-analysis

Evaluate $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}x\sin \dfrac{1}{x}$

My attempt:
I made quite a few attempts but could not really figure out which one was correct. Highly none of them was. So, I show them.

My first guess was that the limit doesn't exist as LHL and RHL might not be equal. My second approach was

$\lim\limits_{t\to \infty}\dfrac{\sin t}{t}$.

Since, $-1\le \sin t\le 1$ and $t\to \infty$ or $t\to -\infty$ so the limit is $0$.

But, I think there is some mistake in my approach. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

$$0 \leqslant |x \sin(1/x)| \leqslant |x|$$

Comment: Use squeeze theorem on it?

Comment: @Swadhin: Yes!!